# How can i access localhost XAMPP on Mac Osx from a windows 7 pc?

Tags: windows, macos, xampp, localhost

Im currently on a mac installed, ran and hosted a local website using xampp. i want to access my localhost website from my windows 7 computer

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming question. You should use google or post this on XAMPP blogs. 
But I'm in a good mood, so I'll tell you :)

For this you have to get the IP-Address of your mac. Go to your system preferences -> network. Enter the IP in the browser of your windows machine and voilà. Also, make sure both PCs are in the same network.

**EDIT**

Forgot the following, you have to grant access to it.

http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=150713

Comment: Doesn't matter, the config files are the same. The xampp files are located under C:\xampp\

Comment: ik where the files are located.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean it :D